# Undefined method `dangerous_class_method?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, error-handling, enums

I'm trying to use enums from ActiveRecord::Enums module in a non ActiveRecord class.

I have a simple class like:

```
class Factory
  extend ActiveRecord::Enum

  enum state: [:active, :inactive]
end
```

But I get an error message like:

> "undefined method `dangerous_class_method?' for Factory:Class"

I don't know where the problem is and if I google this error message I'm getting no helpful results.

Any proposals?

Thank you!

Best regards Kumaro

Comment: What are you trying to do? I haven't seen someone extending ActiveRecord::Enum before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending `ActiveRecord::Enum` when you shouldn't. When you call [enum](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L81) it calls [detect_enum_conflict](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L169) which calls [dangerous_class_method?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.5.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb#L149).

If you want to use an `enum` inside a object that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base (a Model), you shouldn't have a problem.

The documentation for Enum says: *"Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database, but can be queried by name."* I don't think you can use this outside of and ActiveRecord::Base child.

Comment: What do you mean with the first part? Why it is not possible to call enum from ActiveRecord::Enum Module? I dont want to inherit ActiveRecord::Base for this Model. It should be possible to import/include/extend the Enum Module to use enum without that.

Comment: I was simply following the code and telling you why are you getting that error. It seems, from the source code and documentation, that you are supposed to use enum, only inside an ActiveRecord::Base child, because it depends on it, Ruby alone has no problem extending a module.

Comment: @Kumaro "It should be possible ..." - why would you think that?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev I thought it ^^. So do you mean that it is not possible to use a single ActiveRecord Module in a non ActiveRecord::Base class because I dont want to create a DB table for this class.

Comment: @Kumaro: yes, that's what we're saying.

Comment: @Leito Thank you for editing your answer. I think this should be the problem. Thx.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Thank you!

Comment: @Kumaro, your welcome! Just for completion sake: You can still create table-less models and there are modules (specially within ActiveModel, that help you with that) that you can include, but many other modules aren't supposed to be used in that way and will raise issues like the one you encounter.